# Read NSURLresponse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

i am sending an object to this adrees : `https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`

with `NSUrlconnection`
and i am trying to read it with this delegate method :

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`
like this :

`NSlog(@"%@",response);`
i am getting this code :

`<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7d2c6c0>` 
i need to get a string somehow.
how can i read it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wrote this answer to another question, but I think it will help you. Have a look in particular at the methods

`-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`

and

`-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

---

```
-(void) requestPage
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://the.page.you.want.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:20.0f];


    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] retain];
    delegate = target;
}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{   
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response; 
        //If you need the response, you can use it here
    }
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (connection == adCheckConnection)
    {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //You've got all the data now
        //Do something with your response string


        [responseString release];
    }

    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
}
```

Comment: but how to address multiple requests?? for example when a connection is going on and another request is coming before the connectiondidfinishloading then chances are that the responseData may get released right??

Comment: @raghul Yes, that's possible. To circumvent that, I'd probably wrap this in a class "ConnectionHandler" so that each connection would have it's own instance of `responseData`

Answer (score 6):

```
NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
int errorCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
NSString *fileMIMEType = [[httpResponse MIMEType] lowercaseString];
```

For more information, check iOS Docs : `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

And be patient: not all connections return `NSHTTPURLResponse`

Comment: i am getting 200 wich is ok...
but how can i read apples server response?

Comment: 200 means that you connection was correctly established and you can start to receive data

Answer (score 3):

If you expect that the connection is receiving some data you can use.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

you can then simply convert data to `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass and override the `- (NSString*) description` method.