# Run code on background and get return code

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have this method

```
    - (BOOL)connectedToInternet
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                          returningResponse:&response error: NULL];

    return ([response statusCode] == 200) ? YES : NO;
}
```

that method is taking a few seconds to do it, im using it in a simple if conditional to know if i have internet connection.

is there any way to do it in a background thread without having to change all code.

I'm calling it this way

```
if([self connectedToInternet])
```

So if i do it in a background thread i cant get the return value and then my method cant return the value.

If i have to change all it doesn't worth it.

I hope u can understand my question and thanks for any help.

Comment: Why can't you get the return value of you run it on a background thread?

Comment: if i use [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:] to run it i cant get the return value on the same method. i would have to send return to another method and then the call will not work untouched.

Comment: @userXXX How about a callback?

Comment: I think the right way to do this is detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036895/read-nsurlresponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this using blocks;

definition (.h)

```
+ (void)isConnectedToInternet:(void (^)(BOOL connected))block;
```

implementation (.m)

```
+ (void)isConnectedToInternet:(void (^)(BOOL))block
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

        if (block) {
            block( ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) ? YES : NO);
        }
    }];
}
```

then call it like

```
[MyClass isConnectedToInternet:^(BOOL connected) {
        if (connected) {
            // do stuff;
        }
    }];
```

Comment: That can be what i need but xcode say that i cant access response inside block
No visible interface for NSURLResponse...

Comment: Also you should check for error, if error != nil, connected = NO; and you are welcome :)

Comment: I think theres no need to do anymore, it works fine without internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

In Apple's "Reachability" [Code Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) note the `reachabilityWithAddress:` method please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly what you want to do, but what you want to use is probably :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //your asynchronous code here
});
```

But by using an if condition, you need the result in order to continue, don't you? So why running the code in background?

Comment: Thats the point, i need the result but i dont want to block ui thread

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the method which you are implementing to know 'if Internet is connected or not' is not the most optimized one... few days back I also tried to implement the same thing.. and I came across couple of solutions, over Internet.. and I wrote about it on my blog.. [Checking Internet connection in cocoa.](http://daemonconstruction.blogspot.in/2012/12/checking-internet-connection-in-cocoa.html)

My preferred way to know if network is connected or not is by using **Reachability** class. You can get clue on using it from this code: [NetworkCheckUtility.](https://github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/NetworkCheckUtility)

Hope this helps :-)